# The behavior of rmbedding of a specific version of a document is unexpected

Tags: python, versioning, eve

I'm using Python REST API Framework quite successfully, and I thank its authors for providing it.

According to the (sparse) documentation, it is possible to apply embedding of a specific version. Consider the following example directly copied from the doc at http://python-eve.org/

```
 DOMAIN = {
     'emails': {
         'schema': {
             'author': {
                 'type': 'dict',
                 'schema': {
                     '_id': {'type': 'objectid'},
                     '_version': {'type': 'integer'}
                 },
                 'data_relation': {
                     'resource': 'users',
                     'field': '_id',
                     'embeddable': True,
                     'version': True,
                 },
             },
             'subject': {'type': 'string'},
             'body': {'type': 'string'},
         }
     }
```

Here, 'author' is a schema with '_id' and '_version' fields in every email document.

A. Assuming my front-end is running Javascript, when I apply the statement

```
Restangular.one('emails', some-id).get({embedded: {"author": 1}}).then(
```

to retrieve an email document with a given id and request the embedding of the author document, I get the latest version of the author and not the version indicated in the _version field of the author of the email document. Why not respect the version? Is there a way via some magical configuration to force the embedding of the version indicated therein?

BW, the workaround is quite easy---simply suppress this automatic embedding, and instead first retrieve the email document, and then retrieve the specific version of the author, but this is counter intuitive.

B. The manual list a configuration attribute called 'embedded_fields', which specifies, and I quote, a list of fields for which Embedded Resource Serialization is enabled by default. A would expect that even if this field specifies that author should be embedded by default, the statement

```
Restangular.one('emails', some-id).get({embedded: {"author": 0}}).then(
```

will override the default. Well, it doesn't. Again, why? or perhaps it is simply a bug.

Answer (score 2):

What version of Eve are you using? There were issues with embedded versioned documents pre-0.6, but they should have all been resolved in commit [b92890](https://github.com/nicolaiarocci/eve/commit/b928907a87f940808e2f2e5ada32016ab2b5025a/). Try upgrading to v0.6.1, or let me know if you are seeing problems post 0.6.

Comment: Apparently I was using a version older than 0.6. Indeed, version 0.6.1 works as expected---both issues I raised have been resolved.